# Criar ícone de app de site responsivo

Tags: android, ios

Eu tenho site já todo responsivo e tal,

- Só que eu não queria que o usuário precisasse acessar o navegador pelo celular para poder acessar meu site.
- Queria postar um app do meu site no google play por exemplo, onde ele baixasse e esse app levasse ele direto paro site. tipo o App do Mega Curioso, acho que o facebook também faz isso.

Alguém sabe me dizer alguma técnica para fazer isso?

Comment: Fazer um aplicativo, não é? Depois de finalizar coloque nas lojas.

Comment: Basta fazer um aplicativo, criar uma `Webview` nele para exibir seu site e publicar nas lojas. Da uma olhada https://www.youtube.com/rafaelaugustos

Comment: Ser responsivo é totalmente irrelevante para o site ter um ICONE. Fora que o titulo fala uma coisa mas a pergunta é mais sobre "PlayStore", me parece um problema de XY: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um app em cada linguagem chamando um web view. Depois é só postar nas lojas e você terá o que deseja, porém é importante salientar que sua navegação não soará nativa e talvez o usuário se sinta enganado.

**Web View Android**

Uma view que exibe páginas da web. Esta classe é a base sobre a qual você pode rolar seu próprio navegador da Web ou simplesmente exibir algum conteúdo online dentro da sua atividade. Ele usa o mecanismo de renderização do WebKit para exibir páginas da Web e inclui métodos para navegar para a frente e para trás através de um histórico, aumentar e diminuir o alcance, realizar pesquisas de texto e muito mais.

[Fonte](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

**[Web view IOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)**

Comment: No caso WebView, qualquer usuário que tenha celular com qualquer versão do android, consegue usar meu app, ou o webview foi colocado em uma das versões do android?

Comment: Posso te afirmar que existe desde o 4 para cima, que ja é a maior parte dos celulares que temos rodando.